# Dispatch action from actionCreator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I studied the react redux example ([shopping cart](https://codesandbox.io/s/shopping-cart-cbype?file=/src/actions/index.js:382-446)) and saw this implementation of action **addToCart**.

The question is, where do the **dispatch** and **getState** arguments come from?

```
export const addToCart = productId => (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (getState().products.byId[productId].inventory > 0) {
    dispatch(addToCartUnsafe(productId))
  }
}
```

I tried to copy it in my [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-franklin-vnoy2?file=/src/actions/index.js:43-90), but I can't get it to work.

PS:
i can make this with **mapDispatchToProps** in [my example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-counter-s084g?file=/src/containers/counter-button.js:712-762)

Comment: For what it's worth, that example is showing a very outdated style of redux. Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, immutable reducer logic, container components/connect/mapStateToProps or createStore. It is also just a fourth of the code. Please read the official tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: Thank you **phry**! I will definitely read the proposed documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They come from the thunk middleware. It allows redux action creators to not only return simple objects (with a type property), but also async functions. The middleware calls these async functions and passes dispatch and getState as arguments. Which in turn allows you to dispatch multiple other actions, look at the current state, and generally have precise control over async flow. Thunk is just one of many middlewares that support async stuff within redux actions.

Comment: Thank you respected **timotgl**, easy solution for my case

    import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
    const middleware = [ thunk, middlewarelogger];
    export default createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middleware));